# Accepting json from both javascript's Jquery.post and Python's request.post

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a flask restful server. I am able to post from Python shell using `request.post` when I go like this in the post method (on the server):

```
def post:
  get_data = request.get_json()
  obj_data = json.loads(get_data)
```

But the same thing fails, if I try to post using Ajax from js:

```
json_data = JSON.stringify(data)   

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url:'mysite',
  data:json_data,
  dataType: "json"
})
```

And, the error is `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

If I remove the json.loads from the server like below, the JS code runs but Python fails with error `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

```
def post:
    get_data = request.get_json()
```

What changes should I make to make the server accept request from both JS and Python ?

Comment: `get_json()` parses the JSON, you don't need to call `json.loads()`.

Comment: Where is the `iteritems` error happening?

Comment: @Barmar: When I try to iterate over get_data `for k, v in get_data.iteritems()`. Same iteration works with the `json.loads()` but not without it.

Comment: What does `print(get_data)` show?

Comment: How can it work with `json.loads()` if that gets an error?

Comment: It sounds like you're sending the JSON differently when you use `request.post()`. You need to show the Python code so we can see the difference.

Comment: output of get_data `{"name": "value"}`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662450/python-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems

Comment: @Barmar: I have removed a line from python code `json.dumps(data_to_be_sent)` and now directly sending the data (which is a dictionary) like this :                      `requests.post("url", json =  data_to_be_sent, headers = headers)`. And it's working. ( 'Content-type':'application/json')

Comment: you are sending string not json . `JSON.stringfy` converts json to string ?

Comment: @Macintosh_89: Am confused again, I thought stringify is for  conversion into JSON.

Comment: `JSON.stringfy` will convert JSON data to string with JSON notation. It won't be an object. You python will see it as a string not JSON object. [see this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)